# vue js как вставить компонент в компонент Can't resolve 'components/Login' in

Tags: vue.js

Нужно в компонент Register вставить компонент Login

Ошибка Can't resolve 'components/Login' in

Register.vue и Login.vue лежат в папке components.

Register.vue

```
<script>
import Login from 'components/Login'

export default {
  name: 'Login',
  components:{
    Login
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: `from './Login.vue`?

Comment: Так же вам стоило бы изменить name у компонента Register, не путайте vue :)